# Looking for examples showing usage of UDP source element in a C++ gstreamer application

Tags: udp, uri, gstreamer

I've been reading the documentation but it's a little tough to see how to set up a pipeline in C++ using the UDP source element.
If anyone knows of an example, or could post a snippet showing how to do it, I'd be very grateful.

Is it enough to do

source = gst_element_make_from_uri(GST_URI_SRC, "udp://@:15004", "source");

and then use the result as the first element in a pipeline?

Comment: [here](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good/tree/tests/examples/rtp?h=1.6) are rtp examples, I think they work very similar (RTP is UDP based protocol with packet counting ability), why dont you just use [udpsrc](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-udpsrc.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User otopolsky answered this adequately for my purposes in the comment above, saying:

here are rtp examples, I think they work very similar (RTP is UDP based protocol with packet counting ability), why dont you just use udpsrc? – otopolsky Jan 28 at 8:21